# Restructure query without sub-query but join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, amazon-redshift

I am trying to rewrite the following query without using sub-query since I cannot afford hash join.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(wins.bid) as wins, 
  to_char((TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + bidRequestTime * INTERVAL '1 Second'), 'DD') as date,
  COUNT(impression.bid) as impression, 
  lid, 
  COUNT(b.bid) as requests, 
  ROUND(SUM(spendCalc),2) as spend 
FROM (
  SELECT lid, bids.bid,bidRequestTime,price::float*COUNT(impression.bid)/1000::float/.80::float as spendCalc
  FROM bids
  LEFT OUTER JOIN wins on wins.bid = bids.bid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN impressions impression ON impression.bid = bids.bid
  WHERE bidRequestTime BETWEEN 1470614400 AND 1471219200 
  GROUP BY price, bids.bid, bidRequestTime, lid
) b
LEFT OUTER JOIN wins on wins.bid = b.bid
LEFT OUTER JOIN impressions impression ON impression.bid = b.bid
WHERE bidRequestTime BETWEEN 1470614400 AND 1471219200  
GROUP BY lid, date
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you format the above query a little to make it more readable?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say you can't afford hash join... what exactly is the issue?  Is this query slow?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 billion record and subquery is taking a lot of time. I believe join would take less time.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a big deal to make query without sub-query if you post sample data and desired output.

Comment: Take your subquery, insert the result set into a temp table, index the temp table, and use it with the rest of your joins.

Comment: I cannot put the results into temp table because I have to run this query frequently and I am expecting billions of rows in the output.

Comment: Why are you frequently running a query with billions of rows?

Comment: @dfundako - To generate reports

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly what your problem is... but here are some tricks removing the outer joins and using a CTE to reduce the search space.... may or may not work, would need to see more details about your model to be sure.

```
WITH mybid as
(
  SELECT bid, bidRequestTime
  FROM bids 
  WHERE bidRequestTime BETWEEN 1470614400 AND 1471219200  
)
SELECT 
  COUNT(wins_bid) as wins, 
  to_char((TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + bidRequestTime * INTERVAL '1 Second'), 'DD') as date,
  COUNT(imp_bid) as impression, 
  lid, 
  COUNT(b.bid) as requests, 
  ROUND(SUM(spendCalc),2) as spend 
FROM (
  SELECT wins.bid as wins_bid, lid, bids.bid, bidRequestTime, impression.bid as imp_bid,  price::float*COUNT(impression.bid)/1000::float/.80::float as spendCalc
  FROM mybid as bids
  LEFT OUTER JOIN wins on wins.bid = bids.bid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN impressions impression ON impression.bid = bids.bid
  GROUP BY price, bids.bid, bidRequestTime, lid
) b
GROUP BY lid, date
```

Comment: Thanks Hogan! I am trying to write the query with no subquery at all, just joins.

Comment: @RedshiftGuy that is not possible since you are doing a two different group bys.  I don't don't know the business rules so I can't verify you can do it with one group by, but it should not matter since I took out all the outer joins here.